# How to stop the hiding of dropdown content in specific situation in materialize?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I have made a dropdown with materialize library. It contains list of items. Now I want to have view more link at the bottom of all the items. The link is added successfully but the problem is that when I click that that link dropdown/select gets closed.

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select");

const fillSelect = (newOptions) => {
   const options = select.querySelectorAll("option");
   options.forEach((x) => x.remove());
   newOptions.forEach((opt) => {
      
      const optionElement = document.createElement("option");
      optionElement.innerHTML = opt;
      select.appendChild(optionElement);
   });
   updateSelect();
};

const addViewMoreLink = () => {
  const link = document.createElement('div');
  link.innerHTML = 'View more';
  link.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  })
  const dropdownContent = select.parentNode.querySelector(".dropdown-content");
  dropdownContent.appendChild(link);
}


const updateSelect = () => {
  window.M.FormSelect.init(select, {});
  
  
}

window.onload = function(){
  fillSelect(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]);
  addViewMoreLink()
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<select id="organization-input">
</select>
```

I want that when I click the view more it should close the select/dropdown content and show new options. Adding new options is not a problem. The problem currently is that it gets closed even though I have used stop `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: I'm sure this could be done natively, didn't have time yet to fix the issue but you could try looking into using onCloseEnd, I might continue looking at it later, as I'm not sure a css hack is the best approach https://jsfiddle.net/bxd18zse/1/

Comment: "I want that when I click the view more it should close the select/dropdown content and show new options." - Can you use 2 selects?

Comment: @Maheer Ali Can you be more specific about what UX behavior you are trying to achieve? If user clicks "view more" should the select dropdown stay open but the options change? Or should it be a truncated list that expands to full list when clicked?

Comment: @maqam7 The UI options should change when user will click view more. Some more options should be added and dropdown should remain opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
  .classic-dropdown .dropdown-content.select-dropdown {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .classic-dropdown .dropdown-content.select-dropdown li {
    pointer-events: all;
  }
</style>
```

```
<div class="classic-dropdown">
  <select id="organization-input">
  </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
const select = document.querySelector("select");

const fillSelect = (newOptions) => {
    const options = select.querySelectorAll("option");
    options.forEach((x) => x.remove());
    newOptions.forEach((opt) => {

        const optionElement = document.createElement("option");
        optionElement.innerHTML = opt;
        select.appendChild(optionElement);
    });
    updateSelect();
};

const addViewMoreLink = (e) => {
    const link = document.createElement('div');
    link.innerHTML = 'View more';
    link.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    })
    const dropdownContent = select.parentNode.querySelector(".dropdown-content");
    dropdownContent.appendChild(link);
}


const updateSelect = () => {
    window.M.FormSelect.init(select, {});
}

window.onload = function() {
    fillSelect(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]);
    addViewMoreLink()
}

document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0]
</script>
```

Comment: Included only 2 properties in css :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is partially working. But it causes another problem. When I click somewhere outside of the dropdown it doesn't hide the dropdown. I want to hide it when I click outside it.

Comment: @MaheerAli your code as is, on chrome, when you click outside of the dropdown it doesn't hide the dropdown :)

Comment: @MharisZafar code should include an explanation of how you did things, only code answers are not encouraged. Please edit your answer and explain what did you do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As you have mentioned you want to close dropdown when you click view more and show new options. So it is good that it gets closed when you click it. Now all you need to do is add new options and then trigger a click event on `dropdown-trigger` so it opens again and show new options. The reason the dropdown didn't get closed when you click outside it is that the body height is equal to it's content height (dropdown container) so you aren't actually clicking on the body. That's why I have set `min-height` on the body inside css.

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select");

const fillSelect = (newOptions) => {
   const options = select.querySelectorAll("option");
   // options.forEach((x) => x.remove());
   newOptions.forEach((opt) => {
      const optionElement = document.createElement("option");
      optionElement.innerHTML = opt;
      select.appendChild(optionElement);
   });
   updateSelect();
};

const addViewMoreLink = () => {
  const link = document.createElement('div');
  link.innerHTML = 'View more';
  link.addEventListener('click', e => {
    fillSelect(["Option 4", "Option 5", "Option 6"]);
    document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-trigger')[0].click();
  });
  const dropdownContent = select.parentNode.querySelector(".dropdown-content");
  dropdownContent.appendChild(link);
}


const updateSelect = () => {
  const instances = window.M.FormSelect.init(select, {});
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  fillSelect(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]);
  addViewMoreLink();
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<select id="organization-input"></select>
```

Comment: The new options doesn't mean previous options will disappear. It will show all 6 options when clicked on view more.

Comment: @MaheerAli So why are you removing them inside your fillSelect function?